# How long will a CGI::Cookie live if -expires is set to -1?

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

If CGI:Cookie is set to `-1` then what does it indicates ?

```
 -expires =>  '-1'
```

How long the cookie will stay alive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl passes expire `-1` unchanged to the browser, and they should expire cookie immediately.

At least so it says [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21).

Comment: @simbabque look what it says about `0` value. It might be that RFC predates browser wars?

Comment: Yeah, I saw. So who's going to go dig in some browser's git repo?

Answer (score 1):

Looking around in the source code of CGI, the expires piece seems to get validated in [`CGI::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.65/lib/CGI/Util.pm). Here is the code that does the deed:

```
sub expire_calc {
    my($time) = @_;
    my(%mult) = ('s'=>1,
                 'm'=>60,
                 'h'=>60*60,
                 'd'=>60*60*24,
                 'M'=>60*60*24*30,
                 'y'=>60*60*24*365);
    # format for time can be in any of the forms...
    # "now" -- expire immediately
    # "+180s" -- in 180 seconds
    # "+2m" -- in 2 minutes
    # "+12h" -- in 12 hours
    # "+1d"  -- in 1 day
    # "+3M"  -- in 3 months
    # "+2y"  -- in 2 years
    # "-3m"  -- 3 minutes ago(!)
    # If you don't supply one of these forms, we assume you are
    # specifying the date yourself
    my($offset);
    if (!$time || (lc($time) eq 'now')) {
      $offset = 0;
    } elsif ($time=~/^\d+/) {
      return $time;
    } elsif ($time=~/^([+-]?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d*))([smhdMy])/) {
      $offset = ($mult{$2} || 1)*$1;
    } else {
      return $time;
    }
    my $cur_time = time; 
    return ($cur_time+$offset);
}
```

It appears that only the `else` block will catch `-1` because it is not followed by one of the specified modifiers.

`-1` will then be returned from this function. Since that is not a valid time, I imagine that the cookie will expire immediately, but I am not sure on that point. It could also cause your request to error out (not sure on this point either).

Answer (score 1):

If you run it, you'll see that it will pass a literal `-1` instead of substituting a timestamp value.

```
use feature 'say';
use CGI::Cookie;
say CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'foo', -value => 'bar', expires => '-1')->as_string;
say CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'foo', -value => 'bar', expires => '-1M')->as_string;

__END__
foo=bar; path=/; expires=-1
foo=bar; path=/; expires=Sat, 01-Feb-2014 14:43:03 GMT
```

Reading through the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) reveals that the format is always this timestamp. One could dig deeper and look at the RFCs that define the behaviour.